# Spring Cloud Eureka on Cloud Foundry: Peer replication among instances on same site

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-netflix

In our case Eureka Discovery service is running on Cloud Foundry. The clients, which also run on CF, register themselves with Eureka and we can see all instances registered okay.

We are also able to use the feature of DS Replica to sync our Eureka servers running on different AZs.

However it's unclear to me how replication between peer instances of the Eureka service works for multiple instances running on same AZ of Cloud Foundry.

Given the Cloud Foundry router exposes all instances of an application on the same  AZ as a single HTTP url, how do the instances sync to give a consistent view of Eureka console whenever accessed?

OR shall one expect it to take an unpredictable time to sync up all instances of a site?

> This is purely a concern for achieving consistent state of Eureka instances from one site of CF. And for information - Though we are running PFC but not using the service discovery tile from PCF.

Comment: Since all instances are available under the same route, and since the router does round robin load balancing, this is indeed an interesting question. But you could make multiple service registries available under distinct routes  in the same AZ, and use these distinct routes to connect them to each other. This way it would work in a very similar manner as with registries on different AZs. Does this help?

Comment: @user152468 yeah that can be an interesting/simple work around. Thanks for suggesting. Just out of interest I would still like to understand/learn the mechanism (if any) that solves my original concern.

Comment: @user152468 - one challenge however I see with the approach is that, with distinct urls there will be no single url that the clients can use to interact with Eureka server. With multiple instances approach, I can still configure the AZ agnostic url (F5 level) for Eureka at my client side to achieve HA and DR. Can eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone take a list of urls while configured at Client side properties?

Comment: In CloudFoundry you can map multiple routes to an app. So for your AZ1, you could have `eureka1.yourdomain.com` pointing to the first instance, `eureka2.yourdomain.com` to the second, etc. Additionally you could have a route `eureka.yourdomain.com` that is mapped to all eureka instances in AZ1. For connecting the eureka servers, you would use the distinct routes, but your clients would connect using the shared route.

Comment: Right, I understand. Missed out the shared-route point.